# DCOM Security using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, permissions, dcom

Are there any methods to change the Access Permissions for COM Security using a batch file? 
I need to write new values to "Edit Limits..." and "Edit Default..." in both "Access Permissions" and "Launch and Activation Permissions" using a batch script. 
I'm using Windows XP machines with Service Pack 2 and 3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the need to create a batch script to grant default Local Activation permissions so that I could run an out-of-process COM component on Windows Azure. After much research, I used a tool called [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) (download link is near bottom of page) to see what changes were made in the Windows Registry when I granted the aforementioned permissions on a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM. Here are the steps I used to determine what changes to make to the registry...

1. Entered `dcomcnfg` in the Command Prompt to launch Component
   Services
2. Launched ***RegFromApp*** program
3. In RegFromApp, selected the ***mmc.exe*** process and clicked ***OK*** to inspect what changes it would make to registry
4. Back in Component Services, expanded ***Component Services*** item in left panel
5. Expanded ***Computers*** item in left panel
6. Right-clicked ***My Computer*** item in left panel and selected ***Properties***
   from popup menu
7. Selected ***COM Security*** tab
8. In ***Launch and Activation Permissions*** box, clicked ***Edit Default***
   button
9. Clicked ***Add*** button
10. Entered `IIS_IUSRS` in empty box, clicked ***Check Names*** button and
    clicked ***OK*** button
11. Ticked ***Allow*** for ***Local Activation*** and clicked ***OK*** button
12. Clicked ***Apply*** button then ***OK*** button
13. Back in RegFromApp program, clicked ***Save As*** from the File menu to save registry
     changes as `SetDCOMPermission.reg` file

Having recorded the registry changes in a .reg file (i.e. the ***DefaultLaunchPermission*** value was modified in the ***[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OLE]*** key), I wrote the following batch script to register my COM component and apply the changes to the registry by running my .reg file...

```
chcp 1252>NUL
OleAutomationFeasibilityModel.exe /regserver
regedit.exe /s SetDCOMPermission.reg
exit /b 0
```

I'm sure you could use a similar technique to record the necessary registry changes for what you're trying to achieve in a .reg file and run this file from a batch script.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any 3rd party tool that allows you to create ACL's programmatically. In the past I've only ever seen this done using custom tooling, e.g. VBScript & a C++ COM component or a native command line tool.

If you do want to go down this route then [Keith Brown's Programming Windows Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604426) is an excellent book on the topic, if a little old these days. It's what I used to work on just such a component some years ago.